# Deleting CalendarItem in Exchange Web Services sends email with meeting time in GMT, not meeting's timezone

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I'm using the unmanaged XML/SOAP calls to talk to Exchange Server 2007, SP1. I can use the `<MeetingTimeZone>` element when creating or updating the calendar item, to specify the timezone of a meeting. This appears to work, and when Exchange sends emails about the meeting it will have a line like this, as desired:

```
When: Sunday, September 01, 2013 1:00 PM-2:00 PM. Eastern Time
```

But when I delete the item, it sends out cancellation emails with a line like this:

```
When: Monday, September 01, 2013 5:00 PM-6:00 PM.
```

The `DeleteItem` call does not have a place for timezone info, unlike the create/update calls. It looks something like:

```
<DeleteItem DeleteType="HardDelete" SendMeetingCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
   <ItemIds> <t:ItemId Id="ABC123..."/> </ItemIds>
</DeleteItem>
```

Anyone know how to get it to send out a correct time in the correct time zone?

Comment: Do you have a <TimeZoneContext> in your SOAP header? I 'brute force' that into every SOAP call I make, and found that saves me a lot of trouble:  <typ:TimeZoneContext><typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/></typ:TimeZoneContext>

Comment: Thanks. No, I do not. I will look into this. I couldn't name a MeetingTimeZone by ID -- unbelievably, I had to define it with nested elements describing the offsets to GMT, and dates for daylights savings time. So my guess is the ID on TimeZoneDefinition will not work and I'll need the nested elements. Not sure how to use them yet.